# Find Minimum and Maximum values within a multi dimensional struct array

Tags: c#, max, visual-studio-2015, minimum

For a school project in learning c# I am making a data collection console application which saves floating point entries for 4 different locations along with the time/date, and user who recorded the entry.  I am required to use a multi dimensional struct array.

I need to have a view that displays the average of the values, along with the minimum and maximum values and the first and last date. I've got the average figured out by counting through the values and adding cumulatively but I can't figure out how to find the minimum and maximum values.

I tried searching and came across this page: http://www.dotnetperls.com/max
I tried to implement this syntax into my code to no avail due to it being a much more complex array.

It worked in my test with integers:

```
class Program
{
    static int[][] intarray = new int[4][] { new int[10], new int[10], new int[10], new int[10] };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        intarray[0][0] = 5;
        intarray[0][1] = 3;
        intarray[0][2] = 10;
        intarray[0][3] = 4;
        intarray[0][4] = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(intarray[0].Max());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above code perfectly displays the number 10! :)

But when I tried to implement this in to my program with a struct array, it doesn't work:

```
class Program
{
    static byte location = 0;
    static float entriesmin;
    static float entriesmax;
    static Entry[][] entriesarray = new Entry[4][] { new Entry[10], new Entry[10], new Entry[10], new Entry[10] };

    struct Entry
    {
        public float value;
        public string user;
        public DateTime datetime;
    }

    static byte LoopEntries(bool display)
    {
        float runningtotal = 0;
        byte entrycount = 0;
        foreach (Entry entry in entriesarray[0])
        {
            if (entry.user != null)
            {
                if (display)
                {
                    string ten;
                    if (entrycount == 9)
                    {
                        ten = "  #";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ten = "   #";
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(ten + (entrycount + 1) + " " + entry.datetime + " " + entry.user + new string(' ', 16 - entry.user.Length) + entry.value);
                }
                runningtotal += entry.value;
                entrycount += 1;                
            }
        }
        entriesmin = (entriesarray[location]).value.Min();
        entriesmax = (entriesarray[location]).value.Max();            
        if (entrycount == 0 && display)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No entries to show!");                
        }
        return entrycount;
    }
```

I need to hand this project in on Monday! I really hope someone can help me! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not a multidimensional array, it's an array of array (a.k.a. a jagged array), but you work with them in a similar way.

To loop through the array of arrays you need a loop in a loop:

```
foreach (Entry[] arr in entriesarray) {
  foreach (Entry entry in arr) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You could use the `Min` and `Max` extension methods to get the minimum and maximum value of each inner array, but you still would have to find the minimum and maximum between those values. As you are already looping through all the entries anyway to get the average you can just keep a record of the smallest and largest values found:

```
float runningtotal = 0;
int entrycount = 0;
float min = float.MaxValue;
float max = float.MinValue;
foreach (Entry[] arr in entriesarray) {
  foreach (Entry entry in arr) {
    runningtotal += entry.value;
    entrycount++;
    if (entry.value < min) {
      min = entry.value;
    }
    if (entry.value > max) {
      max = entry.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm only trying to find the minimum and maximum values of the current location which is set by the user in a different function/screen. e.g. [0-3] The location is saved in a global variable  which defines which sub array I loop through. Which I just noticed I had wrong in my code snippet.. 
`foreach (Entry entry in entriesarray[0])`
should be:
`foreach (Entry entry in entriesarray[location])`
That's why I only have 1 foreach loop.
I don't understand what value the 
`float.MaxValue
float.MinValue`
 represent?

PS: Thankyou for the quick response!!

Comment: @OptimistPrime: Ok, then you can just use the inner loop from my example. The `float.MaxValue` and `float.MinValue` are used to initialise the minimum with the highest possible value and the maximum with the lowest possible value. Those will be replaced by the first values in the loop.

Comment: Perfect!! Yes I figured it out when debugging and looking at the value held in min/max variables on the first run! Thankyou so much for your help, Much appreciated, it works wonderfully! :) Could I do the same thing with DateTime? 
Also, can you please explain why this doesn't work:

`entriesmin = (entriesarray[location]).value.Min();
        entriesmax = (entriesarray[location]).value.Max();`

Comment: @OptimistPrime: Yes, you can use the principle for any value that is comparable. To use `Min` and `Max` methods you would need a transformation function to get each value out of the entries: `entriesmin = entriesarray[location].Min(entry => entry.value);` and `entriesmax = entriesarray[location].Max(entry => entry.value);`. (Note that these will loop the array once each, so you would have three loops instead of one.)